Laravel - Query models that have relationship with daily field in the given date range
I am working on a Laravel field that has a Listing model and this model has many Price models associated. The Price model has a date date field. I want to query the listings that have price entries daily for the given range, but I cannot wrap my mind around how I can achieve this with Eloquent, the only way I could do it is pulling the listings that have some prices at all and having PHP loop through the results, but that is ineffective and resource consuming. I would like to do it with SQL only. Can anybody point me towards a solution?
$query->where(function ($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
    $query->whereHas('prices', function ($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {

    });
});


why not Listing::with(['price' => function ($q) { $q->whereDate('date', now()->today() ); }])->get()

@silver because I want ot to give me listings that have a price entry for each of the days in the given range, not just for today

yeah, I misunderstood your question, I posted an answer based on my recent understanding

You can use join or whereHas + with
using join you can directly apply the whereBetween filter, but make sure the database name and column name are correct,
Listing::join('prices', 'listing.id', '=', 'prices.listing_id')
    ->whereBetween('prices.date', [$startDate, $endDate])
    ->orderByDesc('prices.date')
    //make sure the table column names has no collision
    //if you have the same column name in those tables, you need to be specific with one you select
    //->select('listing.*', 'prices.price', 'prices.date')
    ->paginate(10)

using whereHas + with
Listing::whereHas('prices', function ($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
        $query->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate]);
    })
    ->with(['prices' => function ($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
        $query->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate])
            ->orderByDesc('date')
    }])
    ->paginate(10);


EDIT:
You can run a raw subquery that counts distinct date that should match the total number of days in the given range
$startDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2024-06-01');
$endDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2024-06-07');
// count the total number of days frm your the date range
$totalDays = $endDate->diffInDays($startDate) + 1;

Listing::join('prices', 'listings.id', '=', 'prices.listing_id')
    ->whereRaw("(
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT prices.date)
        FROM prices
        WHERE prices.listing_id = listings.id
        AND prices.date >= ? AND prices.date <= ?
    ) = ?", [$startDate, $endDate, $totalDays])
    ->orderByDesc('prices.date')
    ->paginate(10);


Thank you! But doesn't this return listings that may have one or two prices between that date range, but not daily? The last solution I can think of is to just list all the dates of that range and add whereHas conditions in a foreach loop, checking against each date, but I think that would also be a hacky solution, not necessarily using SQL and Eloquent especially at their full capabilities.

I'm confuse with what you mean by "between date range, but not daily", its better you provide an example data structure and clear example of the result based on the filter you want.

so let's say the date range is 1st of June - 7th of june, I would like to filter for the listings that have a price entry for each 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th and 7th of June, if a listing doesn't have a price entry for any of those dates in that range (let's say 3rd of June) is missing, I need that listing entry to not be returned

edited my answer with new query
